# World hole will not go away!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It's on my modded server, and half of my house is now a 16 x 16 black hole. I tried f3+f and f3+a i tried relogging i tried closing and reopening the server and NOTHING is working. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted chunk. What happens when you walk into the black hole?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but you're probably not getting that half of your house back.  As @Gigazelle says, this is probably because of a corrupted chunk, which can only be fixed server side by means of regenerating the chunk (i.e. lose player changes to the chunk).

Comment: If you have a backup of the world from before the chunk became corrupted, you might be able to restore that chunk back to how it used to be using MCEdit... if not, now you know why you take backups!

Comment: If you're asking questions about modded Minecraft, mention which mods you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You have a corrupt chunk. Sometimes you can use an older or newer client version to see the chunk again. If that doesn't work, you'll have to delete it with MCEdit then reload the world and it will rebuild the area. Sorry about your house, it won't come back if you delete the chunk..